# Include multiple query parameters in HCM cloud rest Get call

Tags: rest, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have an hcm cloud instance. I'm working on the rest api which are provided by the cloud.

I want to get an employee by matching both `PersonNumber` as well as `DateOfBirth`.

But whatever I tried based on the first parameter, I'm getting the output. Second is not even checked. 
Can anyone help?

This is the rest url I'm using

```
https://host:port/hcmCoreApi/resources/11.12.1.0/emps/?q=DateOfBirth=1991-09-19&PersonNumber=240
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing multiple search items in a query parameter in a rest call, the structure should be as following

```
https://host:port/hcmCoreApi/resources/11.12.1.0/emps/?q=DateOfBirth='1991-09-19'&PersonNumber=240
```

**Basically quotes `''` are required around String inputs and integer can be passed directly.**